# "Super editors" in Suggested Edits review?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits

**Are there some "*Super editors*" on Stack Overflow who are able to do more reviews?**

I searched on Meta Stack Exchange and Meta Stack Overflow, however I didn't find an answer to this. Am I wrong to think that the *Suggested Edits* review is stuck to 20 reviews/day? How can these two guys have one more review than allowed? This is the first time I saw this, so I'm surprised.

[image: Suggested Edit review stats]

As I can know (*and maybe I'm wrong*), they are not moderators and do not have higher reputation points (less than 7k reputation points). Then, how is this possible?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If I understand the mechanics properly, you can always approve or reject proposed edits to your own posts, and you are notified for those.

So, you process 20 proposals in the edit queue, and then some new guy has a great improvement for your own work, which gets you to 21. Still, you must be really fast for those or the robo-approvers get them first and you cannot approve, only roll-back if it is really bad.

Comment: If you've completed 19 in one of the queues, and then approve an edit to your own post, does that halt further review efforts, or does the counter effectively ignore the "own posts" entirely?  Just wondering...

Comment: @Dave: Reviewing of edits to your own posts, though itself not limited, is still reviewing.

Answer (score 8):

This is simply because someone edited their post and they reviewed it. Since Stack Overflow does not want to prevent you from deciding whether an edit should be applied to your own post, you are able to reject or accept it whether you have completed your daily reviews or not. This is the same reason why users with less than 2000 reputation points can accept or reject edits on their own posts.

If you do not already have 20 reviews for that day completed and you review an edit on your own post, it adds to your 20, so you need to already have 20 reviews done for this to occur.