# How can someone review more than 20 items in a day?

Tags: bug, review-queues

I noticed a couple of people have exceeded 20 items today, is this possible or just a display bug?

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats

Comment: Because the bug this question is about:  
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262000/i-reviewed-the-same-edit-suggestion-twice

Comment: If there are more than 1,000 items in any particular review queue, the reviews-per-queue-per-user limit is increased to 40.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently, there is a small bug on SO that allows users to duplicate review votes, under certain circumstances.

Someone asked a question about this, earlier:
[I reviewed the same edit suggestion twice?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262000/i-reviewed-the-same-edit-suggestion-twice)

Comment: Good spot, didn't see that when I searched for an existing question.

Comment: I've seen that question pass by earlier today, that made it a little easier to find ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus And in my case, I had the info in my answer from the research I did when asking that question...

Answer (score 14):

There are a few ways.

First, there is the [bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262000/i-reviewed-the-same-edit-suggestion-twice) that I reported today.

Second, if you accept or reject edit suggestions to your own post, [this will be added to the number of reviews you di](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255101/supereditor-in-suggested-edits-review?rq=1)d. And you can always accept or reject edit suggestions to your own posts. See here

Finally, I believe it's possible that you reviewed a post that has been deleted since. This would mean your edit slot becomes available again. But I'm still looking for the reference for that.

Comment: Only seemed right for me to accept @Cerbus answer, though yours has way more info.

Comment: I didn't want to add that info to my answer, since that would just be copied from here, then...