# A rhapsody of triage reviews

Tags: discussion

why can some people review like 41 triage questions?[image: bohemian rocks the day]

I guess it's because they're a moderator, but isn't the 20 reviews limit kind of system enforced or something?

[there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262024/576767) [are](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158335/243821) some other questions about this, but they figure examples with 21 reviews, related to a bug. those are 41 reviews, and definitely do not seem to be caused from a bug.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bill the Lizard's Closing Antics](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202844/165773)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The limit doesn't apply to moderators.

Comment: this explains that.

Comment: Side interesting bit - it doesn't appear that moderators have binding non-unsalvageable (to close) triage votes: http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7369278