# Does skipping multiple questions lead to more audits?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I've been in the review queue lately trying to help out, I often *Skip* questions as they are not in my field and I know nothing about them, this leads me to skipping quite a bit. I've noticed lately that I seem to be getting more and more audits, most of which I seem to be passing.

So, my question is this, *does hitting the Skip button increase the chances of getting an audit* or is there some other reason as to why I am getting audits pretty frequently?

---

Since posting this (25 minutes ago), I've gotten 3 more audits, all of which I have passed. I fully understand the concept of the Skip button and I would rather skip questions that are out of my expertise than misinterpret something and make an uninformed *bad* decision.

Comment: As far as [I know](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4099598/nathan-tuggy?tab=activity&sort=reviews), skipping doesn't increase audits. In particular, I skip a good three-quarters of reviews whenever I head into Suggested Edits, and the audit frequency there is nothing special.

Comment: I would think if anything reduce audits

Comment: What is more and more? What is the interval (as in: how many reviews) in between them? Its not based on time I believe, its on how many reviews you do. Probably a skip adds to the counter. So perhaps you're seeing more and more audits because you do more and more skips :)

Comment: Did you break the 40 limit? That would be an issue. Skipping is skipping: you do nothing -> no audits count increase. You just won't see again that question in your queue.

Comment: @Gimby I would say around 1 in 10 are audits, I'll keep a detailed record when I hit the review queue tonight.

Comment: @FlorinGhita 40 limit? I am only allowed to review 20 questions at a time, I assume this is from having lower rep.

Comment: @enki.dev that's about the frequency I experience too, perhaps every 10-15 reviews. It might depend on the queues you frequent though.

Comment: @enki.dev everyone is limited to 20 reviews per day with two exceptions.  If the queue has too many reviews in it (I forget the exact threshold), everyone can review an additional 20 while it's too bloated.  Currently, this is only true of the close votes review.  Also you can always review a suggested edit on your own post, so [it's possible to review 21 (or more) suggested edits in a day](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255101/super-editors-in-suggested-edits-review?rq=1).

Comment: @ryanyuyu: Just to be complete: If you have mod-priviliges, there's no limit. It's just that mods already have to deal with all the mod-only things like their own queues.

Comment: @Deduplicator I knew I shouldn't have restricted my claim with an actual number.  There's exception number 3.