# Reviewing system bug?

Tags: discussion, bug, review-queues

So I was reviewing today and I've noticed that some guy has reviewed 21 times, when the maximum is 20 a day.

Is it a bug? Or can I review above the limit in a day?

[Here is the url for the review page.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats)

[image]

Comment: No, I was reporting the bug, and then asking if maybe I could review above the limit in case it wasn't a bug.

Comment: My first tought was that the first to get to 20 reviews in the day could review 1 more.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah, now I get it.

Comment: [This question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255101/super-editors-in-suggested-edits-review?rq=1) would be a *much* better duplicate target...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This user [approved an edit to their own post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11296127), which is always allowed. They also did 20 reviews, taking them over the 20 review limit.